# Create new Project failed TF400797: Job extension had an unhandled error:

Tags: tfs

I want to create a new team project in TFS2018. The create fails with error TF400797. After some research I discovered when I choose Team Foundation Version Control the creation of a new project succeeds! So, the problem has to deal with Git as our source control provider. We use TFS as our Git Server.

The version of TFS we use is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Version 16.131.27701.1

Comment: Can you add a Git repo after the project is created?

Comment: No, the creation of the project failed due to this problem.